# Get Ajax Values in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I'm passing the values in angularjs using `$http` to a url but I'm not able to get the values in AJAX file.

The following is my JS code:

```
$scope.insert = function() {
    var name = $scope.name;
    var pass = $scope.password;

    alert(name);
    alert(pass);
    $http({
        url : 'http://localhost/anguler/ajax.php?act=abc',
        data : {"pass":pass,"name":name},
        type : 'POST'
        }).success (function(resp){
            alert(resp);
        });
}
```

And this is the code in **ajax.php**:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['act']) == 'abc')
{
    $user_name=$_POST['name'];
    $password=$_POST['pass'];
    echo $user_name.'**'.$password;
}
```

I'm not getting the values for `$user_name` and `$password`.

Comment: $.http.post(url, $.param(data)).success( function (res) { console.log(res); });

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console on your browser? Also, what comes through in your `alert(resp)`?

Comment: wrap your data with http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Comment: if you wanna see code response from server, add to callback param code after result container

Comment: i'am getting Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\wampnew\www\anguler\ajax.php error in console.

Comment: before handle you data, trace it like this var_dump($_POST); or var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')); and that are you see?

Answer (score 0):

Angular `$http` has another options, check it out:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/anguler/ajax.php?act=abc',
    data: {
        "pass": pass,
        "name": name
    }
})
```

Not `type`, but `method`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Also, you can try to check passing values like 
`isset($_REQUEST['pass']) == 'pass') { do stuff; }`